# PlayOnLinux Fl Studio Wont detect mouse Clicks HELP! ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, mouse, playonlinux, titlebar

So i installed Fl Studio 12 on Ubuntu 16.04 through PlayOnLinux, and opened it up. after a couple of hours of working on a project i opened up chromium from the dash, and used it for 2-3 mins. when i was done i tried switching back to Fl studio by using the *Ctrl* + *Alt* + *Tab*, when i did  i noticed the program was not detecting any mouse clicks. and the window title bar was still on chromium even though i was on fl. the mouse would glitch when i glided it over the program. NOTE: the program is NOT FROZEN, i can clearly see its animations running fine. it has a cpu detector that has animations. it is not frozen. i have a very inportant unsaved project that i need to get back to asap! thanks in advance!! - ben

Comment: Sometimes the minimize still works.  I had the same issue with SimCity 2000 in PlayOnLinux where if I minimize the application then bring it back up it allows me to continue.

Comment: i cant even access the minimize button. the whole thing is under some kind of spell